# How to get ChartJs object from dynamically created chart

Tags: javascript, object, chart.js

I have a LandingPage which loads charts dynamically using chartjs.

I need to get the clicked on chart and get it's property values.

The code defining the charts is inside a loop of retrieved dynamically built columns(bootstrap):

```
var canvasId = columnID.replace("col", "");
    canvasId = parseInt(canvasId);
    var canvasChart = $("#canvas" + canvasId).get(0).getContext("2d");

    chart = new Chart(canvasChart,
        {
            type: type,
            data: { etc etc
```

The onClick event calls a modal popup and sets it's elements, but I need to get the correct chart (each has a different canvas id)

```
function chart_click(colId)
{
    var parentId = $("#" + colId).closest('.colm').prop("id");
    document.getElementById('ChartEditId').value = parentId;

    // Get the chart's properties. The chart (ID) could be 'canvas01,..canvas09'
    var ChartObject =....HELP
    var type= ??;
    var legendPosition= ??;
    var data = ??.data.datasets...:
    etc..

   // Set the modal's elements from the chart properties
   ...code to set modal's elements

    // Show the ChartEdit modalPopup with it's matched elements' property values
    chartEditpopup.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while making the charts store objects in an array with 2 values, the chart object and the id of that chart. That way when you click the chart you pick the right object out of the array.

You can also instead of keeping track of the id's with object only store the chart.js object in an array and make sure the index of the object is in the id then parse the index out and get that element from the array